# Html.DropDownList extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

I have a drop down list in a view bind to a model (MVC4)

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ID_ROLE", String.Empty)
```

ID_ROLE is one of the property of the model

and ID_ROLE is also the name of the viewbag I pass to the view in this way

```
  ViewBag.ID_ROLE = new SelectList(lista_ruoli.OrderBy(x => x.DESCR_ROLE), "ID_ROLE", "DESCR_ROLE", user_to_edit.ID_ROLE);
```

In this way it works..

but I don't understand why I can't find an extension of the HtmlHelper.DropDownList
which fits with

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ID_ROLE", String.Empty)
```

Is this way wrong or not?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want the list to show up in the dropdown, you need to provide the list to the HTML helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID_ROLE", (SelectList)ViewBag.ID_ROLE)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree infact I was trying to understand why it works in the way described above. Any ideas?